# QtConcurrent map with QMap as input sequence

Tags: c++, qt, qthread, qmap, qtconcurrent

I have a data structure of `QMap<QList<QList<float>>>`. I want to compare every single float with a threshold value using multi-threading(as the amount of float is huge, 1000*800*800). However QtConcurrent::map only accepts QList or QVector as input sequence type, but I require the QMap.key() component in my map function to perform other stuff, is there any solution to it? Thank you.

Comment: Manually spawn a thread for each element of the map?

Comment: The data structure `QMap<QList<QList<float>>>` is invalid. Your QMap is missing either a key or value type. Could you please provide a real-world example?

Comment: @MartinHennings sorry I mean `QMap<int, QList<QList<float>>>`

Comment: Looks like you need to refine your concurrent function. Please show us what you have (or what you think should work).